# Yen's & Bannister-Eppstein optimization of Bellman-Ford algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, bellman-ford

I am attempting to implement the optimizations of the Bellman-Ford algorithm proposed by Yen, and the randomized speedup proposed by Bannister & Eppstein in python.

I am following through Bannister & Eppstein's paper on the topic which can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.5414.pdf)

I have been able to successfully implement the original Bellman-Ford algorithm, a variant that includes early termination of the algorithm (exit when no changes to the vertices distance have changed), and Yen's first improvement to the algorithm (algorithm 3 in the paper).

However, I have had some trouble implementing Yen's second improvment, and Bannister-Eppstein randomized improvement (algorithms 4 & 5 in the paper).

The pseudocode given in the paper for Yen's second improvement is

```
1. number the vertices arbitrarily, starting with s
2. C ← {s}
3. while C != ∅ do
4.    for each vertex u in numerical order do
5.        if u ∈ C or D[u] has changed since start of iteration then
6.            for each edge uv in graph G+ do
7.                relax(u, v)
8.    for each vertex u in reverse numerical order do
9.        if u ∈ C or D[u] has changed since start of iteration then
10.           for each edge uv in graph G− do
11.               relax(u, v)
12.   C ← {vertices v for which D[v] changed}
```

The pseudo code for Bannister-Eppstein's algorithm (algorithm 5) is exactly the same as above, expect for the first line which states :

```
1. number the vertices randomly such that all permutations with s first are equally likely
```

I find the language on lines 1 and (4,8) confusing.

What does it mean to "number the vertices arbitrarily / randomly"?

What does it mean to iterate through the vertices in numerical order?

Some additional info about my code: My algorithms take a Graph object as a parameter which has list attributes of vertices([0,n]) and edges([source,destination,weight])

EDIT: Some extra information about the algorithms from the paper:

> "As
>   Yen observed, it is also possible to improve the algorithm in a
>   different way, by choosing more carefully the order in which to relax
>   the edges within each iteration of the outer loop so that two correct
>   relaxations can be guaranteed for each iteration except possibly the
>   last. Specifically, number the vertices arbitrarily starting from the
>   source vertex, let G+ be the subgraph formed by the edges that go from
>   a lower numbered vertex to a higher numbered vertex, and let G− be the
>   subgraph formed by the edges that go from a higher numbered vertex to
>   a lower numbered vertex. Then G+ and G− are both directed acyclic
>   graphs, and the numbering of the vertices is a topological numbering
>   of G+ and the reverse of a topological numbering for G−. Each
>   iteration of Yen’s algorithm processes each of these two subgraphs in
>   topological order."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Fisher--Yates to shuffle the vertices other than s. For example, you might have vertices s, a, b, c, d, e, f and shuffle to f, a, c, e, d, b. Then you can assign consecutive numbers s->0, f->1, a->2, c->3, e->4, d->5, b->6. The numerical order is s, f, a, c, e, d, b. The reverse numerical order is b, d, e, c, a, f, s. The edges in G+ go from a lower numbered vertex to a higher, e.g., c->b. The edges in G- go from a higher numbered vertex to a lower.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was able to get working versions of these algorithms.

For anybody wondering, the Python random.shuffle() method uses Fisher-Yates to shuffle a list.

It is interesting however that the randomized algorithm takes almost 3x as long on my input graph than the normal Yen algorithm. I suppose since the improvements do not modify the worst-case time, it depends on the specific graph weather it provides a practical improvement or not.

Comment: @ASchmalzWorld how do the iteration counts compare? You aren't re-randomizing after each one, are you?

Comment: No I only randomize once. I am currently in the process of calculating the stats for each algorithm, but I did run both algorithms on a DAG I found online with ~ 4 million vertices and ~14 million edges. The Yen algorithm took ~19 seconds while the randomized algorithm took ~ 24 seconds.

I will say that I am using random DAG generation code for automated testing, but the drawback is that the source vertex is always a lower numbered vertex than the destination vertex, so all the edges are in G+.

Comment: @ASchmalzWorld that probably explains it then, since the first pass in topological order gets all of the distance labels correct.